# Rails: Action error in production but not in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Can anyone explain why I keep getting an error in production but not in development? Relevant parts:

```
get: /user/logout
ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant User::SessionController):
  activesupport/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `block in constantize'
  activesupport/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:228:in `each'
  activesupport/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:228:in `constantize'
  actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:69:in `controller_reference'
  actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:54:in `controller'
  actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:32:in `call'
  journey/lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
  journey/lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
  journey/lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
  actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing /route_set.rb:600:in `call'
  omniauth/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:177:in `call!'
  omniauth/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:157:in `call'
  omniauth/lib/omniauth/builder.rb:48:in `call'
  airbrake/lib/airbrake/rack.rb:27:in `call'
```

Routes:

```
Application1::Application.routes.draw do
  match('/auth/:provider/callback' => 'session#create', :format => false)
  root(:to => 'blog/archives#index', :format => false)

  namespace(:user) do
    match('/logout' => 'session#destroy', :format => false)
  end 

  namespace(:blog) do
    match('/archive/:slug' => 'archive#show', :format => false)
    constraints(:page => /page\d+/) do
      match('/archives/:page' => 'archives#index', :format => false)
    end 
  end 
end
```

I am using Rails 3.2.3 with the latest Omniauth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have created a namespace **user** and therefore you should place the **session** controller that defines the **destroy** action in this path:

```
/app/controllers/user/session_controller.rb
```

Then you can do stuff like:

Create a file in `/app/controller/user/base_controller.rb` that defines this:

```
class User::BaseController < ApplicationController
 # Whatever you want here
end
```

And define the sessions controller located in `/app/controllers/user/session_controller.rb` as:

```
class Users::SessionsController < User::BaseController
 def destroy
  # whatever you want destroy to do..
 end
end
```

Read [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing) for more documentation about namespaces and routing.

Comment: Session is a controller on it's own with public interfaces being /usr/logout => session#destroy and /auth/ going to session#create. I do not wish to split a common (shared) controller into parts making management harder.  I can match it directly to session#destroy outside of the namspace but inside it expects what you state, which is what I do not wish as that means when I finish adding in the rest of /user/ I have one route inside of /user outside of the namespace. Also the documentation you pointed to is pretty broad and leaves quite a bit to be explained about :namespaces and my issue.